# Updating cells in Excel using FME SQLExecutor

Tags: sql, fme-form, excel

In version 2013 FME reads and writes Excel worksheets with XLS_ADO. I have several working 2013-workbenches, which update individual cells in Excel worksheets using this SQLExecutor and this format specification. Since version 2014 XLS_ADO is denoted as deprecated, and substituted with XLSXR/XLSXW2.

I can use the new formats with my FME 2014 SP3/32bit instance on a Windows 7/64bit machine (MS Office 2013/64bit installed) for reading and writing. But in SQLExecutor the format is not available any more ("The specified format is not supported by this FME license" and not in the list of available formats). I am using FME ESRI Edition and it should be no license issue.

How to solve this problem? Is it a 32/64bit problem?

Answer (score 1):

No solution, but a workaround: in SQLExecutor transformer select Microsoft Access (MDB_ADO) as the format, edit the SQL string, press ok, save, execute notepad++, open fmw-file, search&replace MDB_ADO with XLS_ADO, add some additional lines (XLS_ADO_SHOW_NAMED_RANGES, XLS_ADO_FIRST_ROW_IS_HEADING), save. Start working.

Obviously FME2014+ recognizes the deprecated format, but doesn't allow to select either this nor the new one from the format list in SQLExecutor.